# Rails 3 - Need help understanding how to QUERY with a WHERE IN (XXXXX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to build a rails query like the following. And would like to learn how so I can do it again on my own.

Pseudo Code:

@usersprojects = ?? Do I get record or just objects here? not sure?

SELECT *
FROM audit_log
WHERE project_id IN (@usersprojects)

IN the where IN () do I some how tell Rails to use the record.id?

thank you so much for helping me learn this. I want to Rails!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@kchau's answer was close, but you need to map out the project_id's from those records, like so:

```
AuditLogs.find(@userprojects.map(&:project_id))
```

Comment: Won't this only work if the primary key of the audit_logs table is "project_id"? And find will only return the first element. I would think you'd want ```AuditLogs.find_all_by_project_id(@userprojects.map(&:project_id))```

Answer (score 0):

So, if `@usersprojects` contained the User's Projects that you're trying to find audit logs for, you would do a query like:

```
    logs = AuditLogs.find(@userprojects)
```

See the Rails [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects) for reference.

Comment: Thank you. But that errord "Couldn't find all AuditLogs with IDs (#<Permission:0x107b34310>, #<Permission:0x107b341d0>, #<Permission:0x107b34108>, #<Permission:0x107b34018>, #<Permission:0x107b33f78>, #<Permission:0x107b33af0>, #<Permission:0x107b33960>, #<Permission:0x107b33848>, #<Permission:0x107b335c8>) (found 1 results, but was looking for 9)"  The usersprojects object contains permission records like so (id, project_id, user_id). that's where I'm stuck.